# Can I copy a piece of code in Vim along with the line numbers?

Tags: vim

I've tried using my mouse, but the line numbers just won't be selected.

How can I copy both the code and the line numbers just as how they look in Vim? I'd prefer a command line approach, BTW.

Comment: You mean with syntax-highlighting and all? If just plain text, use `cat -n file.txt`

Comment: Plain text is ok. Good solution :)

Comment: If you want to copy syntax highlighting too, you can use TOhtml script as described here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Pasting_code_with_syntax_coloring_in_emails

Answer (score 0):

The mouse might work in a terminal (not GVIM), when you let the terminal handle the mouse (i.e. `:set mouse=`).

For a general solution, you have to (temporarily) prepend the line numbers, and then yank / write the buffer. I use the following function:

```
":[range]Number[!] [{offset}]
"           Number all lines in range, or the entire buffer.
"           The first line of the range is number 1, or the actual
"           line number in the buffer if [!] is given.
"
"           Numbering is done in the first column, with
"           right-aligned numbers. Existing numbering will be
"           overwritten, so you can re-apply this command over a
"           range already numbered.
"           The number column width is chosen based on the necessary
"           width.
function! s:Number( line1, line2, isAbsolute, offset )
    let l:offset = str2nr(a:offset)
    let l:startLine = (a:isAbsolute ? 1 : a:line1) - l:offset
    let l:width = len(a:line2 - l:startLine + 1)
    execute a:line1 . ',' . a:line2 . 'global/^/execute "substitute/^\\%(\\s*\\d\\+\\%( \\|$\\)\\)\\?\\(.*\\)$/\\=".string(printf("%' . l:width . 'd", line(".") - ' . l:startLine . ' + 1)) . " . (empty(submatch(1)) ? \"\" : \" \") . submatch(1)"'
    call histdel('search', -1)
endfunction
command! -bar -bang -range=% -nargs=? Number call setline(<line1>, getline(<line1>)) | call <SID>Number(<line1>, <line2>, <bang>0, <q-args>)
```

You can script that like this:

```
$ vim -c 'Number' -c 'write numbered.out' -c 'quit' file.in
```